# SELECT TOP N With Two Variables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following example in a SQL table

```
Cust Group Sales
A   1   15
A   1   10
A   1   5
A   2   15      
A   2   10
A   2   5
B   1   15
B   1   10
B   1   5
B   2   15
B   2   10  
B   2   5
```

What I would like to show is the top 2 products per customer, per group sorted descending by Sales i.e.

```
Cust Group Sales
A   1   15
A   1   10
A   2   15      
A   2   10
B   1   15
B   1   10
B   2   15
B   2   10
```

I'm assuming I need to declare two variables, Cust and Group, I'm just not sure how to complete this in one fell swoop.

Apologies for the thick question...no excuse. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Incidentally, its a 'fell swoop' ;-)  http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/at-one-fell-swoop.html

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I like that correction James...I'll happily take that on the chin and correct everyone else from now on : )

This is currently on old school 2000 Ada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi the following works in MSSQL2000

```
 SELECT tbl.Cust,
        tbl.Group,
        tbl.Sales

 FROM   MyTable tbl

 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM   MyTable tbl2 
        WHERE  tbl2.Sales > tbl.Sales 
        AND    tbl2.Group = tbl.Group 
        AND    tbl2.Cust = tbl.Cust) < 2

 ORDER  BY     tbl.Cust ASC, 
               tbl.Group ASC, 
               tbl.Sales DESC
```

The inner `Select Count(*)` query works by counting how many records are above the record it is currently looking at - in this case you want there to b either 0 (1st place) or 1 (2nd place).

Note that  because of this, if you have more than 2 values sharing the top spot (e.g 3 A/1's all with sales of 15) you will get more than 2 results back.

However, for your test set it returns the correct results and the use of `DISTINCT` will help if you'd rather get less instead of more results in this instance. Additionally if your records have a distinct recordid this may help you to decide between them.

Comment: Thanks, this helped in another query I was just asked to help with.

Comment: Thanks CResults - very useful bit of SQL that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one you need running over SQL Server 2000 :

```
select distinct t1.Cust, t1.GroupID, t1.Sale 
from Test t1 inner join Test t2 on t1.Cust = t2.Cust and t1.GroupID = t2.GroupID
where t1.Sale>t2.Sale
order by Cust, GroupID, Sale desc
```

its equivalence running over SQL Server 2005+ :

```
select Cust, GroupID, Sale
from (
    SELECT *, rank() over(partition by Cust, GroupID order by sale desc) as n 
    FROM dbo.Test
     ) dt
where dt.n<=2
order by Cust, GroupID, Sale desc
```

Comment: Of course it does, if you have inserted the data into a table called Test.

Comment: Do the following `INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('A',1,20)` and re-test